# How do i call a method in a modelTable from a different controller?

Tags: cakephp, orm, associations, cakephp-3.0

I have a method setTotalInDataBase in OrdersTable.php

I tried to call setTotalInDataBase in OrderproductsController.php

like below

```
function setprice()
{
     $ordersTable=TableRegistry::get('OrdersTable');
     $ordersTable->setTotalInDataBase();
}
```

it gives me the below error,

> Error: Call to a member function setTotalInDataBase() on boolean

How do I call a method in a modelTable from a different controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html), even if you want to load the `Table` object, you don't have to specify "*Table*" in the name. So you need to call `Orders` instead of `OrdersTable`.

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

public function setprice()
{
    $ordersTable=TableRegistry::get('Orders');
    $ordersTable->setTotalInDataBase();
}
```